# SQL counting distinct elements of overlapping sets

Tags: sql, count, distinct, set, overlapping

I want to count the number of distinct elements from two sets. Precisely this is the union of set 1 and set 2.

How can I format the following pseudo SQL into functioning SQL

```
select COUNT(set1 union set2) from table1`
```

**EDIT** set1 and set2 are columns of table1

Here is a short example:

Set 1 of students in a class:

```
Bubba, Jody, Rex, Sandy, Jules
```

Set 2 of students in a class:

```
Jody, Rob, Horace, Thor, Rex
```

I want the distinct number of students in both classes:

```
Bubba, Jody, Rex, Sandy Jules, Rob, Horace, Thor
```

So, a union will do and I can just count.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what the sets are? The pseudoquery doesn't make much sense. This can probably be accomplished with a union.

Comment: Hahah yes it supposed to be like a union. Since sets do not have repeated elemetns... I guess it would be more like appending? Or I could just count the elements if I did have a union operation

Comment: You don't need to use distinct with intersect as intersect always returns distinct values. Use "Union" for common and "Except" for left query distinct.

Comment: If set1 and set2 are columns, what datatype are they?  What kind of values are in the columns, like 1 if it's in the set and NULL if not, or something else?  Do you need to count the records in each set, or do you need the distinct values in the set1 and set2 columns?

Comment: Please provide examples of inputs and expected results to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Count(column_alias) From
( Select set1 As column_alias From Table1 
Union 
Select set2 From Table1 )
```

The Union will make the elements unique.  This will only work if the column datatypes are compatible.  You can modify the subqueries to include a Where condition if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 1 in the column means in the set, and a NULL is used for not in the set

```
select count(*)
from Table1
where set1 is not null or set2 is not null
```

If inclusion in the set is represented differently, then re-write the where clause.